# Facebook app in a Page Tab not appearing to non page admin users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I'm having the strangest problem.

I'm trying to publish my page tab iframe app live for all to see, but for some reason it won't appear to anyone who who is not a page admin.

I've added to may page using this code `http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL`

I thought it may be sandbox mode but it's definitely disabled - plus it's not application admins, it's the page admins that can see it. All normal page visitors cannot see it.

This is like my 5th page tab app that i've created an I can't understand why it's not appearing to non page admins.

Is there anything else that I could have missed? I can't find anything different.

Thanks
Josh

Comment: Also you can add your update as an answer and select it as the correct one to close this question.

Answer (score 3):

On the new timeline facebook layout, only 12 tab boxes are visible at one time to non page admins.

The latest tab application I tried to add, was box number 13 - so hence no one could see it.

When I'm logged in as a page admin, the button which reveals all the tabs, has a number 9 in it. If I then view the page as a non admin, it says number 8 - and there is no option to expand or see the extra hidden tabs.

The tabs at the end of the tab list are hidden, and only 12 are visible.

Hope this helps someone.

As far as I can tell, where ever you position the like count tab box, if it's past number 12, it will swap places with the number 12 spot. So it is always visible.

[image]